# How to fix legato errors on repeats

Tags: lilypond, repeats, slurs

I'd like to fix two errors with legato appearance near the repeat sign.

1. I'd like the legato before the repeat (inside the 1st volta) to extend slightly to the right from the A note to emphasize that it connects to the beginning of the repeat.
2. I'd like the slur (that I created with \repeatTie command) to be up not down, however, I do not understand how to control it.

This is the code:

```
\version "2.22.2"

upper = \relative c' {
  \clef treble
  \key a \minor
  \time 4/4
  \tempo "Moderato" 4 = 94
  
  r1 |
  r2 r4 e8( a |
  \repeat volta 2 {
  b2. c4 |
  a2) r4 e8( a |
  b2. e4 |
  c2) r4 e4( |
  b2) r4 r8 c8( |
  }
  \alternative {
  { a2) r2 |
    r2 r4 \slurUp e8( a) |
  }
  { a2\repeatTie r4. g8( |
    b2) r2 |
  }
  }
  
  % Part B
  e8( a, c e f d e c) |
  e8( a, c e f d e c) |
}


\score {
  \new PianoStaff \with { instrumentName = "Piano" }
  <<
    \new Staff = "upper" \upper
    %\new Staff = "lower" \lower
  >>
  \layout { }
  \midi { }
}
```

[image: excerpt and miss-matched slurs across volta repeat]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controlling the direction of a *single* tie or slur etc. is better done with `^` for up, and `_` for down.

You can control the shapes of these curves with the `\shape` command, (see [modifying shapes](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/notation/modifying-shapes)).  The pairs of numbers specify the coordinates of the "control points" of Bézier curves, (play around with these to see what they do).

If you upgrade to v2.23 (which I'd generally recommend) you can use `\vshape` to see exactly where these control points are, (see [modifying shapes, v2.23](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/notation/modifying-shapes)). This helps in choose the best coordinates, but is not necessary.

You should get something like this:

```
...
\alternative {
    { 
        a2) r2 |
        r2 r4 
        \shape #'((0 . 0) (0 . 0) (2 . 0) (2 . 0)) Slur
            e8^( a) |
    }
    { 
        \shape #'((0 . 3) (0 . 3) (0.5 . 3) (0.5 . 3)) RepeatTie
            a2^\repeatTie r4 r8 g8( |
        b2) r2 |
    }
}
...
```

[image: slur and repeat tie with modified shapes]

---

Comment: Heh, I'm glad to see that \vshape (which I added) is seeing some use :-)

Comment: @ABOUSAMRAJean Thank you _so_ much. Bézier curves really are a lot easier to work with when you can actually _see_ the control points.

Comment: You'll probably want to get the repeat-tie under the 2. to look like the slur under the 1., so you'll have to adjust the control points a bit.